# CoreData Basics Help

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data, uidatepicker

**EDIT**:
I have altered the NSPredicate as recommended so that my fetch code look like so. Having printed to the UITextView like this, when I press load it spits out the following:

```
<NSManagedObject: 0x1c7cf0>(entity: DatedText; id: 0x1420c0 <x - coredata://B52D4F88-0210-4AE2-9DA6-C05ED64FE389/DatedText/p12> ; data: <fault>)
```

So either its not getting any data data because it hasn't been saved/loaded correctly or I am trying to get the loaded result into a UITextView the incorrect way. Any ideas?

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *testEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DatedText" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetch setEntity:testEntity]; 
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dateSaved == %@", datePicker.date];
    [fetch setPredicate:pred];

    NSError *fetchError = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjs = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&fetchError];
    if (fetchError != nil) {
        NSLog(@" fetchError=%@,details=%@",fetchError,fetchError.userInfo);
        return nil;
    }
    NSString *object = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[fetchedObjs objectAtIndex:0]];
    noteTextView.text = object;
```

I have been having all sorts of problems working out how to use Core Data, so I have gone back to basics, new window based ipad project using core data.

I have added a view and some code which doesn't work, hehe. Im basically trying to save some text to a date, then when going back to that date, the text which was previously saved will be shown again.

Comment: which bit doesn't work? is it crashing? or just not doing what you expect? have you tried stepping through with the debugger and setting breakpoints? ie set a breakpoint after various steps are taken, then have a look at the variables and make sure they contain what you expect. put your findings here and i will pop back and have another look.

Comment: Mr project: http://www.mediafire.com/?1x77zf8x21i84d1 Feel free to take a look. I have found that it crashes when it reaches: `NSArray *fetchedObjs = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&fetchError];` in `loadNotes`.

Comment: Don't just point people to your project (again), describe the problem you're seeing or the question you have about it.

Comment: Also, you should describe the actual crash, not just say it crashes.  That would have helped people much more easily.

Comment: You should be more specific when posting questions and at least include the error message you are getting. Nevertheless, I've had a look at your project and the solution is outlined in my answer below.

Comment: Edited to include perhaps more useful information. Sorry if I am being to vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your project and aside from having to synthesize the CoreData properties, I also just noticed you were trying to assign an NSArray to your fetch predicate, but it actually expects an NSPredicate object. You should use this instead:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(dateSaved == %@)", datePicker.date];
[fetch setPredicate:pred];
```

If you want to set more than 1 predicate you should do that on your predicate string i.e.

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(dateSaved == %@) AND (dateSaved <= %@", datePicker.date, [NSDate date]];
```

Cheers,
Rog

Comment: This has certainly stopped its failing at that line, thanks! However my issue is now getting the object from the array and putting that text into the UITextView. check original post please, interesting error.

Comment: That is not an error. If you want to get the text value for the saved object, you need to use noteTextView.text = [[fetchedObjs objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"savedText"];

Answer (score 3):

There's a tutorial on iPhone developer site [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html). And there are several [sample codes](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+C#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code) with Core Data as well. These should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely crashing because your ivar is `managedObjectContext_` but you are using `self.managedObjectContext`. You also need to synthesize the core data ivars even if you provide a custom getter.

Comment: I have tried using `managedObjectContext_` before with no success nor after synthesising the core data variables.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your NSFetchRequest's predicate to an NSArray, not an NSPredicate.

If you had posted the actual crash, it would probably say something like an unknown selector was sent to an instance of NSArray.